# as3 removeEventListener not working

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

This is driving me crazy. Why don't the removeEventListeners work?

Class constructor

```
public function item(brand:String, title:String, price:Number, mp:Number, 
       path:String, sb1:*, sb2:*):void
```

sb1:* and sb2:* are object hooks.

These are assigned listeners:

```
_sb1.addEventListener("Changed", slideBarChanged); // Price
_sb2.addEventListener("Changed", slideBarChanged); // MegaPixels
```

This function is called:

```
private function slideBarChanged(e:Event):void
{           
switch(e.target.type)
{
    case "Price": 
        if(int(e.target.currVal) > Math.abs(this.price))
        {
            this._active = false;
            _sb2.removeEventListener("Changed", slideBarChanged);
        }
        else {
            this._active = true;
            _sb2.addEventListener("Changed", slideBarChanged);
        }
        break;

    case "MegaPixels": 
        if(int(e.target.currVal) > Math.abs(this.mpixels))
        {
            this._active = false;                           
            _sb1.removeEventListener("Changed", slideBarChanged);
        }
        else { 
            this._active = true;
            _sb1.addEventListener("Changed", slideBarChanged);
        }
        break;          
}
```

Everthing works, but the listener isn't removed when the item goes _active = false;
Effectively this should work like this:

If the price is too high then ignore the megapixels and only listen to the price. 
If the megapixels are too high then ignore the price and only listen to the Megapixels.

breaking my brain, any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanx.

Comment: I think the first thing to do would be to separate the functions. Have a megapixelChange and a priceChange function. Also there's only one "this._active". How do you know which is active or not? It could be something with your case statements where you never reach the proper "removeEventListener"

Comment: do you ever create new instances of the object hooks and assign them to _sb1 and _sb2?

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
e.target.removeEventListener("Changed", slideBarChanged);
```

as opposed to

```
_sb1.removeEventListener("Changed", slideBarChanged);
```

or

```
_sb2.removeEventListener("Changed", slideBarChanged);
```

Also on a separate note, you should parse a constant instead of a string literal for the type parameter of the addEventListener() and removeEventListener() methods.

```
const CHANGED:String = "changed";

_sb1.addEventListener(CHANGED, slideBarChanged); 
_sb1.removeEventListener(CHANGED, slideBarChanged);
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, Just in case anybody is hoping for an answer, this is what I've done.

SIMPLIFY

The logic looks like this now and it WORKS exactly as I want it to.

```
private function slideBarChanged(e:Event):void
{           
 if((int(this._sb1.currVal) > Math.abs(this._price)) || (int(this._sb2.currVal)) > Math.abs(this._mpixels))
 {
  this._active = false;
 }
  else this._active = true;
}
```

Thanx for all your help - much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding event listeners multiple times. Removing the listener may not remove it all.

In the following example:

```
else {
    this._active = true;
    _sb2.addEventListener("Changed", slideBarChanged);
}
```

You can either add an extra conditional with .hasEventListener, or you can do my preferred method. Remove the event listener on the line before you add it again. It's silly, but if you attempt to remove the listener before you add it in every instance, you'll never duplicate. Also, Flash silently ignores you if you try to remove a listener that doesn't exist.

This problem of multiple listeners is fixed in Flex with some Flex specific handling, but it still pops up in Flash.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I haven't grokked all the code, but if I were to guess, I would say that maybe the type declaration for your objects is the cause. e.g.,

```
sb1:*, sb2:*
```

What happens if you change them to:

```
sb1:IEventDispatcher, sb2:IEventDisptacher
```

Easy to try anyway.

Comment: No Change. Still not removing listener

Answer (score 0):

Adobe's doc show:

Removes a listener from the EventDispatcher object. If there is no matching listener registered with the EventDispatcher object, a call to this method has no effect.

Probably it does not find it.

RemoveListner method is:

```
public function removeEventListener(type:String, listener:Function, useCapture:Boolean = false):void
```

You might want to add useCapture when calling method.

useCapture:Boolean (default = false) — Specifies whether the listener was registered for the capture phase or the target and bubbling phases. If the listener was registered for both the capture phase and the target and bubbling phases, two calls to removeEventListener() are required to remove both, one call with useCapture() set to true, and another call with useCapture() set to false.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of the [CasaLib](http://casalib.org/). There are a lot of base libraries that are extended. one of them is [RemovableEventDispatcher](http://as3.casalib.org/docs/org_casalib_events_RemovableEventDispatcher.html)

you can try the library and see if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the willTrigger() method to determine whether the listener is really active? Also, have you tried running a trace in there to make sure your code is actually being called?

Comment: Like I said in the OP, everthing works as designed but listeners not removed

Comment: I'd recommend writing a test case in FlexUnit of some sort to demonstrate that listeners are failing to be removed. See: http://pastebin.com/NMqKyN0N

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be nothing wrong with the way your listeners are assigned and removed in the code you've shown.  I would suspect one of the following:

a) Standard UI elements in Flash use the [`Event.CHANGE`](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/events/Event.html#CHANGE) constant to propagate changes, which resolves to the string "change", while your listeners are all assigned to "Changed".  If just once you've added a listener to the native "change", your event listeners would correctly be called whenever the value changes, but `removeEventListener ("Changed",...)` would never work.  In any case, you should always use string constants instead of character sequences when you assign or remove listeners, to avoid spelling mishaps.

b) Your `event.target` does not resolve to the actual slideBar object, but to some nested `DisplayObject` using a [bubbling](http://www.rubenswieringa.com/blog/eventbubbles-eventcancelable-and-eventcurrenttarget) event.

c) The stage instances of your slideBars are not the same objects referenced in _sb1 and _sb2.  This could happen if you create a new instance of the slideBar at some point, but never update the item's variables.  To avoid this, you could use `event.target.removeEventListener()` instead of addressing _sb1 or _sb2 explicitly.

d) Something is wrong with your logic.  Are you certain the `removeEventListener` calls are ever made?  Perhaps the if statements never evaluate to true?  This could be the case, if either side of the comparison is `NaN`, or if the slideBar values are miscalculated.

I also do not understand why you would want to remove the listeners at all - it seems you are creating some sort of filter mechanism, and while it makes sense to set `this._active` to `false` if the item is not in the specified range, you'd still have to listen for slideBar changes to reactivate it at a later time.

Comment: a) Not usung standard UI, using my own slideBar Class that dispatches change event on mouseUp.